# PHP - LDAPHelper Class not found

Tags: php, symfony

I've finished a web site that runs on my computer and on the old server. The problem is that the old server is dying and my employer wanted to move it to a new server.

When he moved it, one web page shows me an error:

```
The autoloader expected class "Equips\FrontendBundle\Helper\LDAPHelper" to be defined in file "/var/www/sinfratic_dev/src//Equips/FrontendBundle/Helper/LDAPHelper.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

and it's like "what?" because I haven't done anything of that part (I just worked with another part of the web). And I've checked that file and inside there is the class "LDAPHelper".

I know what a server LDAP is, but I don't know if that problem is because the new server cannot communicate with out LDAP server or it doesn't have all things installed (I've installed ldap-auth-client, ldap-auth-config, libaprutil1-ldap, libldap-2.4-2, libldap2-dev, libnss-ldap, libpam-ldap and php5-ldap; things that were on the old server but not in the new, but it still doesn't work).

Any idea? 
Thanks you so much.

---

EDIT

Thanks for the comment. Here is the header of the file:

```
<?
namespace Equips\FrontendBundle\Helper;
class LDAPHelper {
```

Comment: it's a pure php issue (nothing related to ldap). Could you give us the begin of your LDAPHelper class ?

Comment: @alicenara Take your connection details out of there before some neckbeard puts your LDAP server through its paces.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was PHP and something unexpected.

By default, short_open_tag is off, so this .php could not be readed properly.

Just needed to put it on in php.ini.